# setImageResource or setImageDrawable doesn't show image

Tags: java, android, layout

I'm trying to set the image resource/drawable within a layout. However, when I set the image, there is no image shown in the output and no errors are seen.

```
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_layout, container, false);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    cardView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recent_conversions_list, null);
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    ...

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.unit_icon_ring);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_angle_icon);

    ...

    return rootView;
```

It is also worth pointing out that the ImageView I am setting an image resource for is not contained within the main layout being used within the fragment. R.layout.fragment_card_layout sets R.layout.recent_conversions_list as a listitem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the static resource file "R" contains a reference to the layout specification, not the object. Setting R.layout.recent_conversions_list as the container for the listview is not enough - it will build it's own copy.

You need to create an ArrayAdapater and set the image for each item there:

http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/31/android---create-a-custom-multi-line-listview-bound-to-an.aspx

In your case, the ArrayAdapter should have a part in it like this:

```
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.unit_icon_ring);
 imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_angle_icon);
```

Or if you use the ViewHolder model, then your ViewHolder object should set some ImageView variable with a viewHolder.setImage(R.drawable.ic_angle_icon) type method.

Comment: How would I set the ViewHolder for an ImageView?

Comment: Nevermind, this helped me figure it out: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/